# How can I make the default "scroll area" bigger while dragging + dropping an element?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have a list of elements that the user can re-arrange by dragging and dropping them. My problem is: When they need to scroll up or down while dragging and dropping? They can only do so by holding the mouse on a very tiny sliver at the very top and bottom of the screen. Only then does the "scroll" functionality get triggered.

How can I make it so this scrolling gets triggered when the mouse is positioned within a much larger area? Let's say the present "scrolling area" is 30px tall. How can I make it 120px tall instead?

Here is the relevant code.

The HTML:

```
<div id='mainparent'> // The main interface div, where the scrolling happens
<div id='DivTesting'> // The parent div container containing the repeating elements
<div id='SavedIdeaDivContainer1'> // Repeating element #1, which can be dragged + dropped
</div>
<div id='SavedIdeaDivContainer2'> // There are lots of these, dozens or more
</div>
<div id='SavedIdeaDivContainer3'>
</div>
</div>
<div id="itemClip" class="item itemClip hide"></div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.box .item');

        var targetEl;
        var wrapper = document.querySelector(".box");
        var itemClip = document.getElementById("itemClip");
        
        var scopeObj;
        
        // === Event Binding ===
        for (var j = 0, max = elements.length; j < max; j++) {
          elements[j].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDrag);
          elements[j].addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
          elements[j].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter);
          
          elements[j].addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouch);
          elements[j].addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
          elements[j].addEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
        }
        
        // === Function Kits ===


        function handleDrag(event) {
          targetEl = event.target;
          targetEl.classList.add("onDrag");
        }
        
        function handleDragEnd(event) {
          targetEl.classList.remove("onDrag");
        }
        
        function handleDragEnter(event) {
          wrapper.insertBefore(targetEl, event.target.closest(".item"));
        }
        
        function handleTouch(event) {
          defineScope(elements);
          targetEl = event.target;
          itemClip.style.top = event.changedTouches[0].clientY + "px";
          itemClip.style.left = event.changedTouches[0].clientX + "px";
          itemClip.innerText = event.target.innerText;
          itemClip.classList.remove("hide");
          targetEl.classList.add("onDrag");
        }
        
        function handleTouchEnd(event) {
          itemClip.classList.add("hide");
          targetEl.classList.remove("onDrag");
        }
        
        function handleTouchMove(event) {
          itemClip.style.top = event.changedTouches[0].clientY + "px";
          itemClip.style.left = event.changedTouches[0].clientX + "px";
          hitTest(event.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
        }
        
        function hitTest(thisX, thisY) {
          for (var j = 0, max = scopeObj.length; j < max; j++) {
            if (thisX > scopeObj[j].startX && thisX < scopeObj[j].endX) {
              if (thisY > scopeObj[j].startY && thisY < scopeObj[j].endY) {
                wrapper.insertBefore(targetEl, scopeObj[j].target);
                return;
              }
            }
          }
        }
        
        function defineScope(elementArray) {
          scopeObj = [];
          for (var j = 0, max = elementArray.length; j < max; j++) {
            var newObj = {};
            newObj.target = elementArray[j];
            newObj.startX = elementArray[j].offsetLeft;
            newObj.endX = elementArray[j].offsetLeft + elementArray[j].offsetWidth;
            newObj.startY = elementArray[j].offsetTop;
            newObj.endY = elementArray[j].offsetTop + elementArray[j].offsetHeight;
            scopeObj.push(newObj);
          }
        }
```

Thanks!